# Обновить запись в БД по условию Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите, как написать функцию на SQL (Postgresql 9.6.4), которую требуется закинуть в cron, чтобы она обновляла данные каждый день.
Имеются поля `days_left, date_1 (yyyy-mm-dd), date_2 (yyyy-mm-dd), date_3 (yyyy-mm-dd)` и т.д (до 9). Как пройти в цикле по всем записям и обновить `days_left`, если текущая дата меньше первой, то высчитать количество дней и обновить запись в `days_left`, если больше, то смотреть следующую.

Псевдокод

```
if (date.now() < date1){
    days_left = date_1 - date.now();
    UPDATE days_left;
} elseif (date.now() < date_2){
    days_left = date_2 - date.now();
    UPDATE days_left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним запросом, примерно так:

```
update table
   set days_left=extract(day from
         now() -
         (case when now() < date1 then date1
               when now() < date2 then date2
           end))
  where date1 > now() or date2 > now()
```

Запрос предполагает, что поля дат типа date или timestamp, как им и положено быть. Если они другого типа, приводите его к timestamp и лучше храните в таком виде.

Но, делать это вообще *не рекомендуется*. В правильно спроектированной БД не должно быть полей, которые надо менять по расписанию и так же не должно быть полей, значения которых можно вычислить исходя из данных той же таблицы (или даже других таблиц). Вместо этого *рекомендуется* убрать поле days_left из таблицы и везде, где необходимо явно вычислять его значение по такой же формуле, как приведена в update. При желании можно сделать view с вычисляемой колонкой days_left.